# Sorting a Data Frame by Month with Repeating Years, based on Unique 'Other' Column

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, columnsorting

In pandas, I am trying to sort rows of a large data frame by months. At the moment, the months are out of order. They are sorted alphabetically, but I would like to sort them chronologically.
The tricky part is that I am sorting by a cycle of 21 months for every one product. There are two year columns, one for calendar year and one for fiscal year, and they differ on purpose. Fiscal Year 2021 is January 2021 - September 2021, and Fiscal Year 2022 is October 2021 - September 2022. There are hundreds of products, and the section below is just a sample of two products.

As seen in the table below, the months are out of order, but everything else is in the right order.

Again, ever product has 21 months, from January 2021 to September 2022. I want these to iterate in order for every product.

I am looking for a code to sort this data frame in the right way.

**How it looks now (months not chronological by year):**

| Item | Calendar Year | Fiscal Year | Month | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product 1 | 2021 | 2021 | April | 45 |
| Product 1 | 2021 | 2021 | August | 85 |
| Product 1 | 2021 | 2021 | February | 25 |
| Product 1 | 2021 | 2021 | January | 15 |
| Product 1 | 2021 | 2021 | July | 75 |
| Product 1 | 2021 | 2021 | June | 65 |
| Product 1 | 2021 | 2021 | March | 35 |
| Product 1 | 2021 | 2021 | May | 55 |
| Product 1 | 2021 | 2021 | September | 95 |
| Product 1 | 2021 | 2022 | December | 125 |
| Product 1 | 2021 | 2022 | November | 115 |
| Product 1 | 2021 | 2022 | October | 105 |
| Product 1 | 2022 | 2022 | April | 405 |
| Product 1 | 2022 | 2022 | August | 805 |
| Product 1 | 2022 | 2022 | February | 205 |
| Product 1 | 2022 | 2022 | January | 1005 |
| Product 1 | 2022 | 2022 | July | 705 |
| Product 1 | 2022 | 2022 | June | 605 |
| Product 1 | 2022 | 2022 | March | 305 |
| Product 1 | 2022 | 2022 | May | 505 |
| Product 1 | 2022 | 2022 | September | 905 |
| Product 2 | 2021 | 2021 | April | 4000 |
| Product 2 | 2021 | 2021 | August | 8000 |
| Product 2 | 2021 | 2021 | February | 2000 |
| Product 2 | 2021 | 2021 | January | 1000 |
| Product 2 | 2021 | 2021 | July | 7000 |
| Product 2 | 2021 | 2021 | June | 6000 |
| Product 2 | 2021 | 2021 | March | 3000 |
| Product 2 | 2021 | 2021 | May | 5000 |
| Product 2 | 2021 | 2021 | September | 9000 |
| Product 2 | 2021 | 2022 | December | 12000 |
| Product 2 | 2021 | 2022 | November | 11000 |
| Product 2 | 2021 | 2022 | October | 10000 |
| Product 2 | 2022 | 2022 | April | 40000 |
| Product 2 | 2022 | 2022 | August | 80000 |
| Product 2 | 2022 | 2022 | February | 20000 |
| Product 2 | 2022 | 2022 | January | 10000 |
| Product 2 | 2022 | 2022 | July | 70000 |
| Product 2 | 2022 | 2022 | June | 60000 |
| Product 2 | 2022 | 2022 | March | 30000 |
| Product 2 | 2022 | 2022 | May | 50000 |
| Product 2 | 2022 | 2022 | September | 90000 |

**How it should look (months in order):**

| Item | Calendar Year | Fiscal Year | Month | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product 1 | 2021 | 2021 | January | 15 |
| Product 1 | 2021 | 2021 | February | 25 |
| Product 1 | 2021 | 2021 | March | 35 |
| Product 1 | 2021 | 2021 | April | 45 |
| Product 1 | 2021 | 2021 | May | 55 |
| Product 1 | 2021 | 2021 | June | 65 |
| Product 1 | 2021 | 2021 | July | 75 |
| Product 1 | 2021 | 2021 | August | 85 |
| Product 1 | 2021 | 2021 | September | 95 |
| Product 1 | 2021 | 2022 | October | 105 |
| Product 1 | 2021 | 2022 | November | 115 |
| Product 1 | 2021 | 2022 | December | 125 |
| Product 1 | 2022 | 2022 | January | 1005 |
| Product 1 | 2022 | 2022 | February | 205 |
| Product 1 | 2022 | 2022 | March | 305 |
| Product 1 | 2022 | 2022 | April | 405 |
| Product 1 | 2022 | 2022 | May | 505 |
| Product 1 | 2022 | 2022 | June | 605 |
| Product 1 | 2022 | 2022 | July | 705 |
| Product 1 | 2022 | 2022 | August | 805 |
| Product 1 | 2022 | 2022 | September | 905 |
| Product 2 | 2021 | 2021 | January | 1000 |
| Product 2 | 2021 | 2021 | February | 2000 |
| Product 2 | 2021 | 2021 | March | 3000 |
| Product 2 | 2021 | 2021 | April | 4000 |
| Product 2 | 2021 | 2021 | May | 5000 |
| Product 2 | 2021 | 2021 | June | 6000 |
| Product 2 | 2021 | 2021 | July | 7000 |
| Product 2 | 2021 | 2021 | August | 8000 |
| Product 2 | 2021 | 2021 | September | 9000 |
| Product 2 | 2021 | 2022 | October | 10000 |
| Product 2 | 2021 | 2022 | November | 11000 |
| Product 2 | 2021 | 2022 | December | 12000 |
| Product 2 | 2022 | 2022 | January | 10000 |
| Product 2 | 2022 | 2022 | February | 20000 |
| Product 2 | 2022 | 2022 | March | 30000 |
| Product 2 | 2022 | 2022 | April | 40000 |
| Product 2 | 2022 | 2022 | May | 50000 |
| Product 2 | 2022 | 2022 | June | 60000 |
| Product 2 | 2022 | 2022 | July | 70000 |
| Product 2 | 2022 | 2022 | August | 80000 |
| Product 2 | 2022 | 2022 | September | 90000 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First convert values to [ordered categoricals](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/categorical.html), so possible sorting by multiple columns in [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
cat = ['January','February','March','April','May','June',
       'July','August','September','October','November','December']
df['Month'] = pd.Categorical(df['Month'], ordered=True, categories=cat)
df = df.sort_values(['Item','Calendar Year','Month'])
```

Or create `DatetimeIndex`, so possible sorting by `Item` with datetimes:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['Calendar Year'] + df['Month'], format='%Y%B')
df = df.rename_axis('dt').sort_values(['Item','dt']).reset_index(drop=True)
```